# Algolia vue instantsearch dynamically set search query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, algolia, vue-instant-search

I have a search bar on the root component (App.vue). I want to enter a query and on `@keyup.enter`, it should redirect to the `Search` component view with the `v-text-field` input value. Redirection is used by using `$router.replace` because users might search for a different keyword from within the same route.

The code below work but only **ONCE**. If I enter a new search term, the URL changed but the results stay the same.

## App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header>
      <v-text-field @keyup.enter="goToSearchPage($event)"></v-text-field>
    </header>
    <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </div>
</template>
 <script>
    export default {
      methods: {
        goToSearchPage($event) {
          this.$router.replace({
            name: "Search",
            query: { q: $event.target.value }
          });
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

## views/Search.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ais-instant-search
      index-name="dev_brunjar_products"
      :search-client="searchClient"
      :search-function="searchFunction"
    >
      <ais-hits>
        <ul slot-scope="{ items }">
          <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.objectID">
            {{ item.name }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ais-hits>
    </ais-instant-search>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchClient: algoliasearch(
        process.env.VUE_APP_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
        process.env.VUE_APP_ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY
      )
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // According to Algolia's doc, this should be inside data instead of methods
    // https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/vue/#widget-param-search-function
    // But doing so, I wouldn't be able to get this.$route.query.q
    searchFunction(helper) {
      var query = this.$route.query.q;

      if (query) {
        helper.setQuery(query).search();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

## What I've tried

Did a hack-ish way (Test 1) to solve it but didn't work (which I'm glad, because it doesn't feel right). Below was the non-working code addition to the Search component. Created computed & watch property of `query` which get its data from `this.$route.query.q` and `algoliaHelper` data assigned with AlgoliaSearchHelper when the `searchFunction` first load.

When I typed a new search term, the watcher works and the query indeed changed. Despite that, calling the helper and setting its query with the new term within the watcher did not change the results from Algolia.

Then I used [Routing URLs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/routing-urls/vue/#basic-urls) (Test 2) to the `ais-instant-search` and it still didn't solve the issue. Maybe I'm implementing it wrong? I really tried to understand Algolia's doc and it's just too hard to digest.

### views/Search.vue - Test 1 (Failed)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ais-instant-search
      index-name="dev_brunjar_products"
      :search-client="searchClient"
      :search-function="searchFunction"
    >
      <ais-hits>
        <ul slot-scope="{ items }">
          <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.objectID">
            {{ item.name }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ais-hits>
    </ais-instant-search>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchClient: algoliasearch(
        process.env.VUE_APP_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
        process.env.VUE_APP_ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY
      ),
      algoliaHelper: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    query() {
      return this.$route.query.q;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    query(newQuery) {
      this.algoliaHelper.setQuery(newQuery).search();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    searchFunction(helper) {
      if (!this.algoliaHelper) {
        this.algoliaHelper = helper;
      }

      if (this.query) {
        helper.setQuery(this.query).search();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

### views/Search.vue - Test 2 (Failed)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ais-instant-search
      index-name="dev_brunjar_products"
      :search-client="searchClient"
      :search-function="searchFunction"
      :routing="routing"
    >
      <ais-hits>
        <ul slot-scope="{ items }">
          <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.objectID">
            {{ item.name }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ais-hits>
    </ais-instant-search>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { history as historyRouter } from "instantsearch.js/es/lib/routers";
import { singleIndex as singleIndexMapping } from "instantsearch.js/es/lib/stateMappings";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchClient: algoliasearch(
        process.env.VUE_APP_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
        process.env.VUE_APP_ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY
      ),
      routing: {
        router: historyRouter(),
        stateMapping: singleIndexMapping("instant_search")
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    searchFunction(helper) {
      if (this.query) {
        helper.setQuery(this.query).search();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I would appreciate it if you guys know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/algolia/doc-code-samples/tree/master/Vue%20InstantSearch/routing-vue-router?file=/src/views/Home.vue

This is an example using vue router. I guess this might be what you're looking for.
Please let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Hey @eunjae.lee, thanks for answering. Although, I already found myself a simple solution. I use `<ais-search-box v-show="false" :value="this.$route.query.q" />` and it works nicely. In terms of performance and best practices, I'm not sure what is lost using the approach. Any reason why I should implement the routing props instead?

Comment: Hey @AfiqRosli , no, if it works with you, then it's fine. The example just shows you how to customize the routing if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you where able to solve this since it's been a long time since you asked. But, in order to make it work you have to put `searchFunction(helper)` inside `data()` as shown in the docs: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/vue/#widget-param-search-function